# Show a Toast When Video reaches its half stage in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

Hello I want to show a simple Toast Message when a video being played in a `Video View` in android reaches half of its total duration. 
What kind of a Listener do I have to have in place to achieve this? I am aware of get `getduration` and `getcurrentposition` methods of Video View. But these wont help unless there is a listener in place which is reading the playback. As far as I know `onprepared listener` is used before the video starts and `oncompletion listener` is used once the video finishes playing. Any pointers and snippets are welcome.

Comment: Well great! Now that you have voted it down. care to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I recall, there's no way to get a notification at a certain time (unless they are in newish APIs). What I would do is onPrepared, get the duration of the video, then implement polling at around the halfway mark. When getCurrentPosition() returns the point at 50%, show your Toast.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have got the duration of the video. actually I want to show various toasts at various intervals during the video. 25%, 50% and 75% to be precise. How do I achieve such polling?

Comment: if you have the duration of the video, you can guess when 25 % will be reached, and use a handler, a timer or whatever mechanism to run something at this point. You'd still need to know when the user changes the position on the track, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697344/monitoring-video-progress-in-android This is what I want to achieve. Sadly the question went unnoticed.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Your answer helped me in building my logic.